# Return a "No results to Show" when then queryset is empty django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

How should I render a "No results to show " if I get a empty queryset.

```
class View(ProjectContextMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "site/project_detail.html"
    model = Ticket()

    def get_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(View, self).get_data(**kwargs)
        project = self.project_assigned()
        if project.tickets.all:
            context.update({
                "project": project,
                "tickets": project.tickets.all()
            })
        return data
```

and my template:

```
<div class="large-12 large-centered columns">
<div class="row">
    <h2>{{ project.heading}} <small><a href="{% url "project-update" project_id=project.pk %}">edit</a></small></h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="1200">Title of assignment</th>
                <th width="1200">Assigned to</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for ticket in tickets %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ticket.title }}</td>
                 .......
```

How should I tailor my context so that I don't break the template. 
I tried using redirect to a different view, Should I give a different template as well ?

Comment: I don't really want to copy and paste an answer, but its the same as the one I just posted about 20 mins ago

Comment: Your issue is, your `ticket_id` is empty but your regex pattern is expecting a digit to match the url pattern. if you resolve that, your issue would be resolved.

Comment: Your edit was a completely different issue, if you have another question you should ask it as a new question. If Shang Wang's answer solved *this* issue, you should consider accepting it

Comment: If it did solve the issue I would accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could do:

```
{% for ticket in tickets %}
    <tr><td>{{ ticket.title }}</td></tr>
{% empty %}
    <tr><td>No results to show.</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

[Django template tag empty](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty).